# Keystore in Rust

Tags: rust, openssl

I'm working on a simple rust application, which as an input takes:

1. Input file path
2. Output file path
3. Keystore path (preferable format: JKS) and password
4. Key id and password

The goal of the application is to encrypt the input file and save it under a specified path.
What are the good practices of using keystore in rust? 
In Java I used to use `java.security.KeyStore`. is there something similar in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any crate that can work with Java KeyStore (JKS) files, but a good alternative is to use PKCS12. In fact, since JDK9 this is the format that [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html) also uses.

You can generate a p12 store using OpenSSL as follows:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -chain -CAfile ca.crt -in client.crt -inkey client.key -passin pass:mysecret -passout pass:mysecret > client.p12
```

You can then use a crate like [openssl](https://crates.io/crates/openssl) to parse it:

```rust
use openssl::pkcs12::*;

fn main() {

    let der = include_bytes!("client.p12");
    let p12: Pkcs12 = Pkcs12::from_der(der).unwrap();
    let parsed: ParsedPkcs12 = p12.parse("mysecret").unwrap();

    let certificate = parsed.cert.to_pem().unwrap();

    let chain = parsed.chain.unwrap();
    let ca = chain[chain.len()-1].to_pem().unwrap();

    let key: Vec<u8> = parsed.pkey.rsa().unwrap().private_key_to_pem().unwrap();

    println!("certificate:\n{}\n\nca:\n{}\n\nkey:\n{}",
             std::str::from_utf8(&certificate).unwrap(),
             std::str::from_utf8(&ca).unwrap(),
             std::str::from_utf8(&key).unwrap()
    );

    test_encrypt(parsed.pkey.rsa().unwrap())
}

use openssl::rsa::*;
use openssl::rsa::Padding;

fn test_encrypt(keypair: Rsa<Private>) {
    let pubkey_pem = keypair.public_key_to_pem_pkcs1().unwrap();
    let pubkey = Rsa::public_key_from_pem_pkcs1(&pubkey_pem).unwrap();
    let msg = "Hello, world!".as_bytes();

    let mut encrypted = vec![0; pubkey.size() as usize];
    let len = pubkey
        .public_encrypt(&msg, &mut encrypted, Padding::PKCS1)
        .unwrap();
    assert!(len > msg.len());
    let mut decrypted = vec![0; keypair.size() as usize];
    let len = keypair
        .private_decrypt(&encrypted, &mut decrypted, Padding::PKCS1)
        .unwrap();
    assert_eq!(len, msg.len());
    let result = String::from_utf8_lossy(&decrypted[..len]);
    println!("Decrypted: {}", &result);
    assert_eq!("Hello, world!", result);
}
```

Not entirely sure from your question if this is what you were looking for though, but the above code parses a p12 and use the public/private key to encrypt/decrypt some data.